# context.SaveChanges() not updating data in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

My ApplictionDbContextClass looks like this :-

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    //private static ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Place> Places { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserTripDetail> UserTripDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TripPicture> TripPictures { get; set; }
}
```

My TripPictureController looks like this:-

```
    //private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly ITripPictureRepository _tripPictureRepository;

    public TripPicturesController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ITripPictureRepository tripPictureRepository)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _tripPictureRepository = tripPictureRepository;
    }
```

It also contains a post Action:-

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(TripPicture model, HttpPostedFileBase ImageData)
    {
        if (ImageData != null)
        {
            model.TripId = 1;
            model.Image = this.ConvertToBytes(ImageData);
        }
        _tripPictureRepository.Add(model);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
        //_db.TripPictures.Add(model);
        //_db.SaveChanges();
        return View(model);
    }
```

When ever i hit the post request, the model is not pushed into database. I am using dependency injection here. My guess is somewhere there is creation of different context object. i saw the following code in startup class :-

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(**ApplicationDbContext.Create**);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);}
```

My unitOfWork class is:-

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private DbContext _context;
    public UnitOfWork(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _context = dbContext;
    }
    public void Commit()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and my repository class is :-

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

The object is saved when i don't use unitOfWork. What is the problem!?

Comment: please provide repository `Add` method and unitOfWork `Commit` method

Comment: I have added the iven unitOfWork and Repository class methods

Comment: "My guess is somewhere there is creation of different context object." I think the same. You can easily verify that by setting a breakpoint inside the constructors of both the repository as well as the unit of work. You can then call `.GetHashCode()` and if the results are different, then the objects themselves are different (as far as I know, `DbContext` does not override `GetHashCode`).

Comment: Please show us how `IUnitOfWork` and `IRepository` are registered with your IoC container.

Comment: Thanks @Balázs , your advice was useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing Unit Of Work pattern incorrectly.

You are adding an item to `_tripPictureRepository` instance DbContext and calling _unitOfWork.Commit() on _unitOfWork instance which has another DbContext instance that has no idea about the added item (Item isn't tracked by the _unitOfWork's DbContext) which means it saves nothing.

The correct implementation of Unit of work is that your repositories should be exposed as properties, a `DbContext` injected to your Unit of work class and `DbSet<T>` of the repository will be populated from the `DbContext` like this:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private DbContext _context;

    public ITripPictureRepository TripsRepository{ get; }

    public UnitOfWork(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _context = dbContext;
        Trips = new Repository<Trip>(_context.Trips)
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Then in your controller inject an IUnitOfWork instance:

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

public TripPicturesController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    _tripPictureRepository = tripPictureRepository;
}
```

And now use the _unitOfWork instance to do your CRUD operations:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(TripPicture model, HttpPostedFileBase ImageData)
{
    if (ImageData != null)
    {
        model.TripId = 1;
        model.Image = this.ConvertToBytes(ImageData);
    }

    _unitOfWork.TripsRepository.Add(model);
    _unitOfWork.Commit();

    return View(model);
}
```

**You can read more about Repository and Unit Of Work patter together from this [Microsoft Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#implement-a-generic-repository-and-a-unit-of-work-class)**.

Comment: Buti am using ninject dependency injection here. Shouldn't it inject same DbContext Object anywhere needed in a constructor?

Comment: The way you pointed out is one way of implementing repository pattern i.e without using dependency injection. My unitOfWork implementation is not wrong coz im using dependency injection, and it has ability to inject same object wherever required, thus my repository and unitOfWork are actually working on same DbContext object.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. My DbContextObjects were different whenever generated by ninject. In my ninject file i was registering services in kernel as following :-

```
kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

This by default uses Transient scope, i.e. new object is created every time required.
hence i needed to change that to following :-

```
kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<ApplicationDbContext>().InRequestScope();
```

The requested scope means - Only a single instance of the type will be created, and the same instance will be returned for each subsequent request.

More can be found here :- https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes